# Mondern Java GUI Framework like WPF or Qt?

Tags: java, wpf, qt, user-interface, styling

does anyone knows a good gui framework for java desktop applications like wpf or qt?
The framework should offer styling and animation features like wpf or qt.

I also want to implement a 3d flip control like:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ContentControl3D.aspx

Thanks

Comment: If you get Desktop look and feel but is Web Application than ok?

Comment: The jambi is Qt for Java. I don't Know others options...

Answer (score 4):

You can use JNI(Java Native Interface).
It is not less than Qt Jambi, moreover it is supported by good forums and Java.

Answer (score 2):

Would QT for Java (Jambi) be possible?

[jambi](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-jambi)

Comment: Yeah but its not longer suppoted by qt or?

Comment: Should be still available somewhere and if the available version has the required features why not use them?

Comment: Qt Jambi is now supported by the open source community.  You can find it at http://qt-jambi.org/

Comment: Thank you! Is there a other rich ui framework for java? (Qt gui module is ok)